# Powershell "You must provide a value expression following the '-' operator"

Tags: powershell, cmd

I found this Tetris source code for powershell https://magicmao.wordpress.com/2011/08/05/tetris-in-powershell/ I saved it as a ps1 file through powershell ISE than ran it through powershell as such & "C:\Path\Path\Path\tetris.ps1"

Then I got this message

```
 "You must provide a value expression following the '-' operator"
```

so I looked up the line where the code is incorrect

```
$sourceLine = $lines[0];
for($k = $sourceLine; $k -gt 0; $k–){
  if($sourceLine -gt 0){
    $sourceLine–;
```

Comment: `$k-` is supposed to be `$k--`

Comment: Same with `$sourceLine-`. You can also remove the `;` from it unless you have other stuff executing in the same line.

Comment: That problem seems to apear in multiple places all over the original script.